# Does AssemblyInfo.cs support SemVer 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to set for SemVer 2.0 for AssemblyInfo.cs like 1.0.0-Beta.1. Currently when I try to do this it give error is it gives error. Is there an alternative way?

> Error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the
>   required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Comment: AFAIK: No, but you could give this NuGet package a try: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Semver/

Comment: Use [AssemblyInformationalVersion].

Comment: For those coming later, this might be of interest: https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/04/sementic-versioning-for-dotnet.html